# Graphic novel with redheaded girl at a magic boarding school

Tags: story-identification, novel

It was a graphic novel that was about two girls in a boarding school. The main girl had red hair and her mother died in childbirth and I think she has a wolf spirit? Also, the other girl's boyfriend turned into a bird? It was a pretty dark series from what I can remember.

I read it when I was a kid (maybe 10-13), and there were animal spirits but not many characters changed into other animals; the boyfriend was more of a side story, and he did change at will. I also think that the school she went to was kind of evil, and the book was in English.

Also, there was this one popular girl who always fenced with another guy she hated but in the end she got together with him.

Answer (score 10):

This is [Gunnerkrigg Court](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gunnerkrigg_Court).

- Boarding school - Check
- Protagonist with red hair - Check
- Mention of wolf spirits - Check
- Dark in tone - Check

[image]

Comment: I have no idea how to talk over this? Do i tag ppl? How?? Anyways, Richard, i love you, thank you so so much !!

Comment: @lola - If this is the correct answer, please upvote it and mark it as accepted with the buttons on the left-hand side of the answer